# JS ClientContext return undefine when deleteObject

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I'm trying to delete a list item from a SharePoint library via JavaScript with ClientContext. 
Unfortunately I don't have access to the ID of the item that's why I use the Title and I can not delete the List Item. All the time I receive the following error on line with deleteObject:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

To use a Title a provide a CamlQuery. If I try to delete it with the comment line everything works perfect, but like I wrote there is no access to the ID of the item.

Here is my code:

```
function deleteListItemSP(title){

    var siteUrl = 'mylink';

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Demo');

    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + Title+ "</Value></Eq></Where>");

    var oListItem = oList.getItems(query);
    //this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(4);
    oListItem.deleteObject();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [SP.List.getItems Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245102(v=office.15).aspx) returns [SP.ListItemCollection object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244833(v=office.15).aspx) not an [SP.ListItem object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245356(v=office.15).aspx).

Second, in your case you have to submit first query in order to retrieve item collection and then only to get the item and delete it, for example:

```
var items = list.getItems(query);
context.load(items);  
context.executeQueryAsync(
  function()
   { 

      if(items.get_count() > 0) {
          var itemToDel = items.getItemAtIndex(0);  
          //delete item goes here...
   },
   function(sender,agrs)
   {
       //error handling goes here...
   }
);
```

Working example

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
var listTitle = 'Contacts'; 
var itemValue = 'Manager';


var context = new SP.ClientContext(url);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + itemValue + "</Value></Eq></Where>");
var items = list.getItems(query);
context.load(items);
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function()
   { 

      if(items.get_count() > 0) {
          var itemToDel = items.getItemAtIndex(0);
          itemToDel.deleteObject();   
          context.executeQueryAsync(
            function()
            { 
                console.log('Item has been deleted succesfully');
            },
            function(sender,agrs)
            {
               //error handling goes here...
            });
      }   

   },
   function(sender,agrs)
   {
       //error handling goes here...
   }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to use a `SP.ListItem` method on a `SP.ListItemCollection` object.  [`SP.List.getItems()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245102(v=office.15).aspx) returns a [`SP.ListItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244833(v=office.15).aspx) object.  You must iterate through this to get to the items themselves.  Try the following:

```
function deleteListItemSP(title){

    var siteUrl = 'mylink';

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Demo');

    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" +
        title+ "</Value></Eq></Where>");

    var oListItems = oList.getItems(query);
    clientContext.load(oListItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        var listItemEnum = oListItems.getEnumerator();
        while(listItemEnum.moveNext()) {
            listItemEnum.get_current().deleteObject();
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
    }, Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

JavaScript is far from my strong point, I'm sure there's a way to get the list item without having to enumerate through them like I did.